# Question About Query in SQL With 2 tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables in sqlserver
table1 is A Header Named : Accounts
Table 2 Is Body Named    : transaction

Accounts :

| AccID | Accname | AccSubCode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Account1 | 3 |
| 2 | Account2 | 3 |
| 3 | Account3 | 1 |

Transaction:

| ID | ACCID | Debt | Credit | Post |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 500 |  | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |  | 300 | 0 |
| 3 | 1 |  | 100 | 0 |

So I want the result show All Accounts Name Where AccSubcode = 3 And Post = 1
then Column show sum( debt ) - Sum (Credit ) as balance Column
I tried Code But it's Show me AccName if only has a Actions in transaction Table
and i want to Get All Accounts Name where AccSubcode = 3 And Post = 1  whith the balance Column even there is no any Actions For AccID in transaction table like this

| AccName | ACCID | balance |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Accounts1 | 1 | 500 |
| Accounts2 | 2 | 0 |

i tried this Code but show only Accounts name if there is a transaction in transaction table

```
  SELECT 
     A.AccName
    ,Max(ISNULL(A.AccID, 0)) AS [AccID]
    ,SUM(ISNULL(T.Debt, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(T.Credit, 0))AS [Balance]
       FROM Accounts AS A
       LEFT JOIN Transaction AS T
       ON A.AccID = T.AccID
        where A.AccSubCode = 3 and T.Post = 1
        GROUP BY A.AccID, A.AccName
```

Comment: on a left join I would not expect t.post to equal 1 for ac 2

Comment: Yeah  I see  . It's work Fine with ne If Transaction Table has AccID .. But i want to sow all  Accid And Name even there is no data in transaction table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To list all accounts even those with post = 0, then join by **AccID** and **T.Post = 1** as follows :

```
SELECT A.AccName,
       A.AccID,
       SUM(ISNULL(T.Debt, 0)) - SUM(ISNULL(T.Credit, 0)) AS [Balance]
FROM Accounts AS A
LEFT JOIN Transactions AS T ON A.AccID = T.AccID AND T.Post = 1
WHERE A.AccSubCode = 3
GROUP BY A.AccID, A.AccName
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/IIc1AdoM)

Comment: Thank You Very Much I wish to you happy Life :)

Comment: Glad to hear I could help you :)